# Unity3d client +.NET Server - recommend network layer

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, websocket, signalr, protocol-buffers

What will you choose for a network layer for a **multiplayer online game**, with the following requirements:

- Server developed in **C#** and the client is developed in
  **Unity3d**?
- Real-time, Bidirectional channel (minimum latency)
- Fast, compact

From my research I'm looking on the following:

*Transport:*

- Websockets vs direct TCP (Using https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html)
- SignalR (any overhead?) , gRPC(good for Real-time?) - both lack official support in the Unity client.

*Data protocol:*

- Protobuf vs flatbuffers. JSON isn't taking into consideration...

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your game. A twitch-based fast first person shooter probably needs highly custom network code to give a good game experience, whereas for a turn-based game any networking solution will work.

FlatBuffers is more game / performance friendly than Protobuf, but the wire format tends to be a bit bigger, and there is no GRPC integration with C# yet (only C++ & Go).

If your game is an action game, you can't really be using TCP or anything on top of it. TCP has built-in throttling/re-sending mechanisms that will wreak havoc with your latency once connections exhibit more packet loss. The only way to do an action game right is to use UDP. There are libraries out there that take care of re-sending reliable data on top of UDP for you (such as Enet for C/C++), but I am not familiar with ones for C#.

Comment: Thanks, my game is an action game. I guess the best will be to use flatbuffers and websockets. (by the way gRPC has C# implementation already http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html)

Comment: I was referring to C# GRPC with FlatBuffers. The existing C# GRPC library expects to be working with Protobuf.